# Why this Superfish menu behaving in an odd way?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, colorbox, superfish

I am using jquery superfish menu and I am using colorbox for images just o give themlightbox effect.

But the problem is when I open colorbox the menu is showing on top of the colorbox.How do I change its z-index or any other property to get rid of this?

Here is what I mean to say.
[image]

This is my menu css:

```
    /*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin:         0px 0 0 -20px;
    padding:        0;
    list-style:     none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0px;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    position:       relative;
    top:            -999em;
    width:          10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
    box-shadow:0px 1px 6px #333;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
    width:          169px;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
    visibility:     inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
    float:          left;
    position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
    display:        block;
    position:       relative;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left:           0;
    top:            40px; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index:        99;
    width:169px;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul, ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul, ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           14em; /* match ul width */
    top:            -1px;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul, ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top:            -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul, ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    left:           10em; /* match ul width */
    top:            0;
}
/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
    float:          left;
    background: url('../images/nav_bg.png') repeat center top;
    width:991px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.sf-menu a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

.sf-menu a:hover {
    padding:10px 30px;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color: #F55D2D;
}


.sf-menu li {
    background:     transparent;
    z-index:9999;
    background: url('') no-repeat top right;
}
.sf-menu li li {
    font-size:12px;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ddd;
    border-left:1px dashed #000;
}
.sf-menu li li:hover {
    border-left:1px solid #F9F9F9;
}
.sf-menu li li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
.sf-menu li li a {
    color:#333;
}
.sf-menu li li a:hover {
    color:#f8f8f8;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    background:#4F5356;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #333;
}
.sf-menu li li li a {
    color:#f8f8f8;
}
.sf-menu li li.sfHover {
    outline:        0;
    border-left:1px solid #F9F9F9;
}
.sf-menu li li.sfHover a {
    color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:active {
    outline:0;
    background-color:none;
}
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
    padding-right:  2.25em;
    min-width:      1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
    position:       absolute;
    display:        block;
    right:          1em;
    top:            1em; /* IE6 only */
    width:          10px;
    height:         10px;
    text-indent:    -999em;
    overflow:       hidden; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
    background-image: url('../images/arrows-ffffff.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -10px -100px;
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
    top:            1.1em;
    background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator, a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator, a:active > .sf-sub-indicator, li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator, li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}
/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position:  -10px 0;
}
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position:  0 0;
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
    background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}
```

Comment: `z-index:0px;` doesn't make sense. :) There should be no `px` after the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .sf-menu li z-index:9999;
```

is the problem, iirc the default colorbox.css uses the same z-index ...

Comment: @roman-thanks for pointing me out.glad that both your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try decreasing the z-index values for the menu. Or increase z-index values for the colorbox css.

Comment: @scott-thanks for pointing me out.glad that both your answers are correct.